# Brownian motion running maximum

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, law-of-large-numbers

Could someone please explain how to find the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$ of the running maximum of a brownian motion $B_t =\max W_t-ut$? Is there a way to calculate the limit itself and not just find the distribution of the maximum? How would this intuitively make sense to be a finite limit, since wouldn't $B$ approach either positive or negative infinity?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you think that such a limit exist ?

Comment: I'm not too sure, it was rather implied from the question and I can't find the intuition behind it (if it is true). More concerned if there is an actual methodology to find the limit itself which will then prove if its finite or not.

Comment: You say the existence of the limit was "implied from the question."  What question?  Where did you find the question?  In what sense should the limit exist?  What have you tried so far?  Why is just finding the distribution of the limit not enough?

Comment: The question is really unclear. Please clarify what are you looking for and what have you tried...

Answer (score 2):

We know that $max W_t = |N(0,t)|$ in distribution thus $max W_t = \sqrt{t}|\xi|$ in distribution, where $\xi \sim N(0,1)$. So $$max W_t - ut = t\Bigg(\frac{|\xi|}{\sqrt{t}} - u \Bigg)$$ where $\frac{|\xi|}{\sqrt{t}} \to 0$ in distribution (and thus in probability) and thus $\frac{|\xi|}{\sqrt{t}} - u \to -u$ in probability. We have $$max W_t - ut = t (-u + o_p(1)) \to - \infty$$in probability.

Comment: I think the question was intended to mean $\max_{t \ge 0} (W_t - ut)$ rather than $\max_{s \le t} (W_s) - ut$